# How to redirect an abitrary window to be rendered to an in-memory backbuffer?

Tags: winapi

I am experimenting with a home-grown application hosting framework, and I'd like to abstract the input/output so I can gracefully handle crashes. Chrome uses a very similar model.

Is there any way I can take an arbitrary window handle, and persuaded it to start rendering to a back-buffer?  Or should I create my own window first, and then reparent the client app into it?

Comment: You can make a window paint itself to a device context you give it using [WM_PRINT](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd145216(v=vs.85).aspx).

Comment: But anyway, if you simply want to separate the business logic in its own process, then the GUI process should own all the windows, and the other process should just communicate it and give it all the info it needs to paint itself.

Comment: @sauton the GUI logic can crash too.  WM_PRINT isn't any good, I need to blt the screen whenever it paints

Comment: Well, you're out of luck then, winapi doesn't provide anything like that, unless you write your own display driver, maybe. That's how remote desktop works.

Comment: It is a very considerable effort with massive api hooking required.  And you'll have to take over the job of the window manager to generate the WM_NCPAINT and WM_PAINT messages.  BeginPaint should be hooked to provide a memory device context instead.  Creating a new session and Remote Desktop Protocol would be a completely different approach.  No idea if that could work.  This is why people use a virtual machine.

Comment: Thanks @Hans.  Could I simply proxy *PAINT and other messages from the 'front-buffer' process window via IPC?

Comment: On Vista and above you can use the DWM (Desktop Window Manager) to automatically copy the contents of a window into another window (this is how the live thumbnails on the taskbar work), but I'm not sure if that's exactly what you're after.

Comment: @JonathanPotter, It seems that it isn't possible to use that thumbnail API to get the data from windows directly... you can only direct its output to be painted to a window.  At least, that's my interpretation from the documentation.

Answer (score 3):

As the comments said you can do anything if you're willing to dig in and hook the APIs themselves, but according to the remarks in [the MSDN WM_PAINT page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd145216%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) WM_PRINT is the supported way to force a window to paint on a specific DC.

It sounds like you also need to keep the window from showing up on the desktop - in that case you can use WM_SETREDRAW as described in [On Win32, can I disable painting of a window for a period of time?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5001566/on-win32-can-i-disable-painting-of-a-window-for-a-period-of-time).

Comment: It is my understanding that `WM_PRINT` isn't universally supported... there are many applications that do nothing with this message.  Is that the case?  What APIs need to be hooked to properly redirect application output?

Comment: As noted above, at the minimum BeginPaint() and all the varieties of GetDC() - possibly even a new display driver.

Comment: Can you elaborate on why a display driver might be needed be needed?