# How does .net paint their forms on screen and where would I find it in the framework?

Tags: c#, .net, windows, winforms, gdi

I am trying to get a better grasp on how applications paint their forms and I figure diving into the framework and doing reflection would be a good way to do this. Although I think I have a good idea though:

1. Application sends message to set form classes.
2. Application sends WM_CREATE message to create window.
3. Application sends WM_PAINT message to paint form.

I know it is a little more complex than that, so I want to find out which dependencies are sending the messages out and doing the drawing. I reflected then sifted through Windows.Forms and System.Drawing to get my answers but I didn't really see anything that painted the initial forms, only ones to draw controls into graphicsbuffers. Either they are well hidden or I am missing something completely. Can anyone tell me how to find the code I am looking for that sends the actual messages out to the system to draw the forms and paint?

Comment: That's done by Windows. winforms is probably calling some `Win32` function to do that. What do you need this for?

Comment: Winforms should use for 90% the Windows controls. WPF is entirely owner-draw.

Comment: @xanatos not true. WPF also calls the underlying WinAPIs for management of `Window` objects. the rest is done via DirectX APIs

Comment: @HighCore Clearly it need the WinAPI for the windows "as a container", but outside of the window as a container, what isn't owner-draw? The menus? Probably even that are custom built, because they are skinnable.

Comment: @Xanatos WPF does not have the concept of "owner draw". All UI elements' visual apperance is defined by `Styles` and `Templates`. And rendered via DirectX

Comment: @HighCore You are right, Owner Draw means another thing. Let's say "drawn pixel by pixel by WPF"

Comment: @HighCore I am trying to be able to control where a form is painted to. I want to draw into a device context or graphics buffer other than the onscreen DC.

Comment: There will be no managed way to do this, but try looking at [this link](http://computer-programming-forum.com/82-mfc/efbfea210cff4807.htm) to help you better understand and look at this [SO Question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13108210/how-to-redirect-an-abitrary-window-to-be-rendered-to-an-in-memory-backbuffer)